# C# await & Task.Run

Tags: c#, async-await

```
     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com");
     }

     private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         HtmlWindow wf = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
         string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
         MessageBox.Show(s);
     }
```

.. this does work... but i need to click two buttons. 
i want to make thoes together. and i wrote below codes... 
the error comes out on second line(nullReferenceException). it seems that await doesn`t work
can anybody help??

```
     private async void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         await Task.Run(() => webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com"));
         HtmlWindow wf = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
         string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
         MessageBox.Show(s);
     }
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on line #2 and tell us what exactly is null here? Is it `webBrowser1` or one of its members?

Comment: I'm assuming that `webBrowser1` is a `WebBrowser` control? If so, then you don't need to worry about async/await, just attach to the [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event?

Comment: are you saying `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com");` works but `await Task.Run(() => webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com"));` doesn't? Where does the magic variable `webBrowser1` come from?

Comment: I'm guessing `webBrowser1.Navigate` returns before the page is fully loaded. You'll have to wait until the `IsBusy` property returns false to show that the page has been loaded, or use the `DocumentCompleted` event (as DavidG said).

Answer (score 1):

Navigate starts the downloading. It returns before the downloading is completed. You'll have to wait for event WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted

By the way, because Navigate does not wait until loaded it is fast, there is no need to call it asynchronously, otherwise Microsoft would have made an async version like in the WebClient task.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com");
}

private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, ...)
{
    HtmlWindow wf = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
    string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **button2** to perform automatically on **button1** event, then you can use the ***Button.PerformClick Method***

So, your code goes this way:

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.naver.com");
     button2.PerformClick();
 }

 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     HtmlWindow wf = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
     string s = wf.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
     MessageBox.Show(s);
 }
```

If you want to make work together, then you can set those button click events on **Form Load** using the **Load** event

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += button1_Click;
        Load += button2_Click;;
    }
```